# About asymptotic field assumption in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, scattering, s-matrix-theory, asymptotics

I'm studying QFT and in a trouble about asymptotic assumption. It states every Heisenberg field converges to free field (asymptotic field) if one takes a limit of $x_0\rightarrow \pm \infty$.
$$
\phi(x)\rightarrow \sqrt{Z}\phi^{\text{as}}(x)
\\
\phi^{\text{as}}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{d^{3}p}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^{3}2p_0}}[a_{\text{as}}(\vec{p})e^{-ipx}+a_{\text{as}}^{\dagger}(\vec{p})e^{ipx}]\\
(\text{as}=\text{in},\text{out})
$$
Where $a_{\text{as}}(\vec{p})$is annihilation operator of asymptotic field.

I'm faced with a contradiction that this makes the theory trivial. Let $|n\rangle,|m\rangle$ eigenvectors of momentum operator$P_{\mu}$.
Then 
$$
\langle n|\phi(x)|m\rangle=\langle n|e^{iPx}\phi(0)e^{-iPx}|m\rangle\\
=e^{i(p_{n}-p_{m})x}\langle n|\phi(0)|m\rangle
$$

And its x-dependence is only phase.
Because of asymptotic assumption and the fact that momentum eigenvectors form a complete set, $\phi(x)=\sqrt{Z}\phi^{\text{as}}(x)$ must holds.

What is wrong with this reasoning?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the point is that you are forcing the theory. The actual *LSZ asymptotic condition* says that (I omit the factor $Z$ for the sake of simplicity) $$\langle \Psi_1| \Phi(f,t)| \Psi_2\rangle  \to \langle \Psi_1 |\Phi^{\pm}(f,t)| \Psi_2\rangle \quad \mbox{for $t \to \pm \infty$}\tag{0}$$
where 
$$\langle\Psi_1 |\Phi(f,t)| \Psi_2\rangle := \int_{x^0=t} \langle\Psi_1 |\Phi(x)| \Psi_2\rangle \: \overleftrightarrow{\partial}_{x^0} \: f(x) d^3x \tag{1}$$ and $f= f(x)$ is any solution of the **free field equation** and rapidly vanishes at spatial infinity. Similarly
$$\langle\Psi_1 |\Phi^{\pm}(f,t)| \Psi_2\rangle := \int_{x^0=t} \langle\Psi_1|\Phi^\pm(x)| \Psi_2\rangle \: \overleftrightarrow{\partial}_{x^0} \: f(x) d^3x \tag{2}$$

Since $\Phi$ in (1) does **not** satisfy the free theory, the right hand side of (1) depends on $t$ and (0) may have sense.

Conversely $\Phi^{\pm}$ satisfies the free field equation and thus the right-hand side of (2) does not depend on $t$. The states $\Psi_i$ belong to a dense set in the Hilbert space generated by repeated application of respectively $a^\dagger_{in/out}(g)$ on the asymptotic vacuum states, where $g$ are *smooth* solutions of KG equation rapidly vanishing at spatial infinity.

You are quite far from the hypotheses written above.

**ADDENDUM**. There is another way, less rigorous, to state the LSZ condition into a fashion more familiar to physicists. First observe that, if $\Phi^\pm$ is the free field in the remote future/past, then
$$i\int_{x^0=t} \Phi^\pm(x)  \overleftrightarrow{\partial}_{x^0}  \frac{e^{-ikx}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^32k^0}} d^3x = a_\pm^\dagger(\vec{k})$$
where it is evident that the right-hand side is independent from $t$.

If we replace $\Phi^\pm$ for $\Phi$, the identity above fails because the interacting field $\Phi$ satisfies an equation different from Klein-Gordon's one. The condition LSZ just says that this is however true if (a) taking the limit for large $|t|$ and (b) referring to matrix elements (I am not sure on signs and coefficients and I omitted the factor $Z$)
$$i\langle \Psi_1|\int_{x^0=t} \Phi^\pm(x)  \overleftrightarrow{\partial}_{x^0}  \frac{e^{-ikx}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^32k^0}} d^3x |\Psi_2 \rangle \to \langle \Psi_1|a_\pm^\dagger(\vec{k})|\Psi_2 \rangle\quad \mbox{for $t \to \pm \infty$}\tag{4}$$
and
$$-i\langle \Psi_1|\int_{x^0=t} \Phi^\pm(x)  \overleftrightarrow{\partial}_{x^0}  \frac{e^{ikx}}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^32k^0}} d^3x |\Psi_2 \rangle \to \langle \Psi_1|a_\pm(\vec{k})|\Psi_2 \rangle\quad \mbox{for $t \to \pm \infty$}\tag{5}$$
In all computations with LSZ reduction formulas only (4) and (5) are exploited.
The popular naive formulation 
$$\Phi(x)\rightarrow \Phi^{\pm}(x)$$
is wrong from several viewpoints and if literally assumed easily leads to evidently false results as the one pointed out by the OP.

Comment: I repeated my calculation with your correction and found it doesn't lead to free theory ,as <0|\Phi(f,t)|n> goes to 0 when |n> is multiparticle state. I'm yet to understand the meaning of LSZ asymptotic condition, it seems that considering only wave packet is important. And the condition is surely enough to deduce its consequences such as LSZ formula. I need

Comment: to be more careful about usage of this condition. Thank you for your clear answer.

Comment: Sorry, my formulas are affected by some typos. Let me some time to correct them

Comment: Well, barring coefficients, I think they are correct. I suggest you to have a look at Sect. II.3.2 of Haag's book "local quantum physics", where these things are discussed with  a quite rigorous approach.

Comment: Also wikipedia gives a nice account  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LSZ_reduction_formula

Comment: Sorry, I need more explanation. In your addendum, I guess LSZ condition is used as f is set to e^{-ikx}. But it doesn't vanish afar. Maybe f can be arbitrary function or can't it be?

Comment: Yes $f$ is replaced by $e^{-ikx}$ in formal, non rigorous, treatments even if this $f$ is not a wavepacket. There should be some "distributional" extension of the formalism where everything goes right anyway even with this sort of functions. The limits in (4) and (5) have to be interpreted as weak (distributional) limits I presume, but I never studied in detail this subject...

Comment: OK. I still don't get the importance of (1). Thank you anyway.

Comment: Field operators are operators when they are smeared against test functions. There are two procedures which are equivalent for free fields. One is the standard one where $\Phi(g)$ is smeared with standard test functions $g \in C_0^\infty(\mathbb R^4)$, the other is a procedure where the field operator is smeared with *solutions* $f$ of KG equation $\sigma(\Phi, f)$. Here $\sigma$ is the symplectic form, conserved for free fields, given by the RHS of (1).

Comment: The LSZ formalism is based on this second smearing procedure.

Comment: Textbook i'm reading doesn't tell about that. I try other books. Thanks